# Fetching string from a Postgres table based on multiple patterns

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have the following column in a table in Postgres database.

```
col1
P02724-PRO_0000012134
P02725
P02724-1
```

I want to apply a regular expression to create a column with following values

```
col2
P02724
P02725
P02724-1
```

I have written following query but the query is unable to fetch 'P02725'

```
regexp_match (col1, '.*-\d+|(.*)-') as col2
```

What changes should I make in the query to fetch this value?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like `^\w+(?:-\d+)?` https://regex101.com/r/1B2Eyi/1

Comment: Thats perfect!! Could you please explain this part (?:-\d+)? . Is this the capturing group here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an alternation, you could make the - and the digit part optional

```
^\w+(?:-\d+)?
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - -\d+`Match`-` and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

Or using a negated character class instead of matching word characters

```
^[^-\r\n]+(?:-\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mfXzgS/1) | [Postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/GYEOL44443)